# MySQL syntax error in the CREATE TABLE statement

Tags: mysql

SQL query:

```
CREATE TABLE  `comment_threads` (
 `comment_id` INT( 11 ) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT  '0',
 `updated` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL ,
 `timestamp` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL ,
) ENGINE = MYISAM ;
```

This is an old file that I'm trying to run on HostGator through phpMyAdmin. I get an error that says:

> MySQL said: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') ENGINE=MyISAM' at line 5

UPDATE:
If I change the statement to this, I still get an error:

```
CREATE TABLE comment_threads (
comment_id INT( 11 ) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
updated TIMESTAMP( 14 ) NOT NULL ,
timestamp TIMESTAMP NOT NULL
PRIMARY KEY ( comment_id ) )
ENGINE = MYISAM ;
```

I get the error:

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '( 14 ) NOT NULL ,
>   timestamp TIMESTAMP NOT NULL
>   PRIMARY KEY ( comment_id ) )
>   ENGI' at line 3

Comment: What? Do you want to run this query through phpmyadmin, then use the sql tab. (you could also use the built-in table-creator)

Comment: MySQL said: 

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') ENGINE=MyISAM' at line 5

Comment: thats the error i get when I import the file thru myphpadmin... 
I aldready read to change all the Types to Engine  and this like here
 `timestamp` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL , used to be  `timestamp` TIMESTAMP (14) NOT NULL ,

Comment: @kevinfantini If my answer was helpful, you can accept it by clicking the checkmark underneath its vote counter. That allows people searching to see that it's correct.

Answer (score 7):

Your MySQL query is incorrect. Correcting it to [this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d010e) works.

```
CREATE TABLE  `comment_threads` (
     `comment_id` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
     `updated` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL ,
     `timestamp` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL
  ) ENGINE=MyISAM;
```

To run this in phpMyAdmin, you can use the [in-built table creator](http://php.about.com/od/learnmysql/ss/create_tables.htm) or enter the corrected SQL statement in the SQL query window.

Note that I removed the comma after the last `TIMESTAMP NOT NULL` line (immediately before the ending `)`.

UPDATE:
The second statement you posted corrects to [this](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/06ca7):

```
CREATE TABLE  `comment_threads` (
     `comment_id` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
     `updated` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL ,
     `timestamp` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(`comment_id`)
  ) ENGINE=MyISAM;
```

Here are the problems you introduced in your second `CREATE TABLE` statement:

1. `TIMESTAMP( 14 )` should just be `TIMESTAMP` (per the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/datetime.html))
2. You need a comma after the line `TIMESTAMP NOT NULL` line. The comma is necessary now because unlike in the first example, you're separated two parts of the statement: the `TIMESTAMP NOT NULL` line and the `PRIMARY KEY` declaration.

If you want more information on simple methods for debugging SQL statements, I strongly suggest you look at my [answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11218752/869912) (see the section titled **A bit more information on how to methodically fix errors like this**).

Make sure that when you change a `CREATE TABLE` statement, or **any piece of code**, that you make changes in small enough increments that you're only "breaking at most one thing at a time." In the case of your second `CREATE TABLE` statement, there was no reason to change the first `TIMESTAMP` declaration, and doing so broke the code. That line was working; no need to change it.

Comment: Next time, ask a new question if you radically change the `CREATE TABLE` statement in incorrect ways (as you did in this case). I'm adding the statement you just posted to your question, and I'll edit my answer with a solution to that as well.